# Rails rake db:migrate has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rake, rails-migrations

I made a new Rails 3 app today, added a simple migration, and for some reason, nothing happens when I do rake db:migrate. It simply pauses a few seconds, then returns to the command prompt, with no errors or anything. Schema.rb and the database stay empty.

Any ideas what could be going on? I've made many apps and never had this problem. Everything is a totally standard setup too.

Comment: Have you tried `rake db:migrate --trace`? What was the output? Also have you tried doing `rake db:rollback; rake db:migrate`?

Comment: What Jakub is getting at is that perhaps it was already run.  Following his instructions should at least give you an indication that your migration was properly run. Also, you could search for your migration inside your file structure as well. It would be inside application_name/db/migrate.

Comment: The output of rake db:migrate --trace was: ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump and rollback, then migrate do nothing either. When I try to migrate with an explicit version, it says the migration doesn't exist. But it's definitely in the standard location, db/migrate.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's a few reasons why your migrations won't run, but the most common is that the system is already under the impression that all the migrations you've defined have already run.

Each migration creates an entry in the `schema_migrations` table with the `version` column corresponding to the identifier number. If you want to force a migration to re-run you can usually back it out and retry it. For example, if you had `20100421175455_create_things.rb` then you would re-run it using:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20100421175455
```

A common situation is that your migration has failed to run in the first place, that it generated an exception for instance, and yet Rails still considers it complete. To forcibly re-run a migration, delete the corresponding record from the `schema_migrations` table and run `rake db:migrate` again.

One way to avoid this kind of problem in the future is to define your migrations with an automatic back-out procedure:

```
class CreateThings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # ... (migration) ...

  rescue
    # If an exception occurs, back out of this migration, but ignore any
    # exceptions generated there. Do the best you can.
    self.down rescue nil

    # Re-raise this exception for diagnostic purposes.
    raise
  end
end
```

If you have a mistake in your migration you will see the exception listed on the console. Since the migration has automatically been rolled back you should be able to run it again and again until you get it right.

Comment: This is one reason not to use MySQL; this stuff is handled automatically with a database that supports transactional schema changes (like postgres).

Comment: I had dropped my table manually and then attempted to use your solution. Anyone reading this, don't do what I did. Let Rails handle your migrations. ;-) If you do what I did, just create a simple little table which Rails can then drop when it's redoing the migration.

Comment: I would add, you can specifically tell rails "that migration didn't happen" by removing the entry from the `schema_migrations` table. E.g. `rails dbconsole` then enter `DELETE FROM schema_migrations WHERE version='...';`. Be careful with this approach, but it's not really as dangerous as it sounds.

Comment: Another approach is to rename `change` to `up` (if you were using `change`) and define an empty `down` method. Then running `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20100421175455` will make Rails forget the migration. Make sure you revert the changes after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I did a kind of a short hack that helped me. I am posting it just in case anyone wants  a short and sweet solution. I agree with what Tadman is saying

> "the system is already under the impression that all the migrations
>   you've defined have already run"

What I did was to change the name of the migrate file in the **/app_folder/db/migrate** folder. I think the numeric part in the name of the ruby migrate file is the time at which the file was created.

You can add say 1 , to the filename, every time you want to re-run the migrate. After changing the name drop/delete the table (I used mysql command line tool for deleting) and then run **rake db:migrate** and the migrations should be done.

Comment: Yep.  This sort of workaround is the only way to fix things when --trace shows no errors, yet it will not rollback or migrate, anymore due to some unkonwn bug.  Can also wipe the whole table and run things from scratch, but make a db-copy first, so you can restore all your data.

Comment: Worked for me magically. But why does this happen in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `spring stop` might solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out what was causing my problem. I'm using the slim_scrooge gem and commenting it out makes everything proceed normally. Don't know why though...

Comment: Maybe you could accept your own answer so that it is clear that the problem is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem today while migrating plugin for Redmine using

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production NAME=plugin_name
```

where plugin_name is actually plugin name defined in init.rb of the plugin.

I struggled for 4 hours and finally figured out that my plugin directory name was not the same as the plugin name (note `redmine_` prefix):

```
~/redmine/plugins/redmine_plugin_name
```

So, make sure your plugin is placed in folder named after plugin name. I believe it applies to other rails apps as well.