# Database Error While Pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

```
PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "name" of relation "restaurants" already exists
: ALTER TABLE "restaurants" ADD COLUMN "name" character varying(255)/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:650:in `exec'
```

this is my table from the schema

```
create_table "restaurants", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "picture"
    t.string   "address"
  end
```

I got the error after running  `heroku run rake db:migrate`

I don't see how I have a duplicate column. I just push this to heroku with `heroku create`, got rid of sqlite3 in both gem and gem lock file then `git push heroku master`.

I have a pg gem, should I be configuring the database before running the migration to install the tables on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely, you have a pending migration that adds this column "name" to "restaurants" table.  You should see this error when you run `rake db:migrate` in your development environment as well.

For your last question, your database is already configured and based on that migration you already are using postgres.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598221/rails-rake-dbmigrate-has-no-effect). If that doesn't work i suggest you to do `rake db:reset` in dev enviroment and check if `rake db:migrate` works as well.