# rake db:migrate is not creating user table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration, rake

I have the following migrations

[image]

Problem is that `rake db:migrate` is not executing the first migration and no `users` table is created.

What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to drop db first? - rake db:migrate:reset

Comment: @NikolaTodorovic: I dropped the db through mysql and now it works. But earlier my db had no tables in it. It was like I had created a new db.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598221/rails-rake-dbmigrate-has-no-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the reason for this?

Main reason is probably that you've already ran the migration - or perhaps later migrations - and Rails therefore does not think it needs to run it.

A good way to see if this is the case is to open your `db/schema.rb` file:

[image]

You'll see the latest migration your schema is running. If this supersedes the one you're trying to invoke, it will not run.

--

**Fixes**

You *could* generate a new migration, and copy the code over:

```
$ rails g migration AddUsers2
```

You'd then add the following:

```
#db/migrate/_____.rb
class AddUsers2 < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :users do |t| 
        t.string :name
        t.timestamps
      end
   end
end
```

Alternatively, you could wipe your DB and start again. This can be achieved using `rake schema:load`. **THIS WILL WIPE ALL DATA AND START AGAIN**