# Rails db:migrate will not run on a certain model class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, rails-models

I am using ruby on rails for a class and had to make a model class that contained a name, gender, age, and homepage. The I run the rails db:migrate command nothing happens

```
josephs-mbp:Soccer jmurphy$ rails db:migrate
josephs-mbp:Soccer jmurphy$
```

All the other model classes have migrations.

Comment: rails db:migrate only works on Rails 5 > .. if you are using a lower version of Rails use 'rake db:migrate' instead.

Comment: make sure you are running the `rails db:migrate` command from within your application root folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails rake db:migrate has no effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598221/rails-rake-dbmigrate-has-no-effect)